# Ar.js with a-frame: user controls where the ar object appears?

Tags: html, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I found this method to build augmented reality in browser apps, so that no installation is needed to run it. I was able to control the ar object that it draws, but not when and where it draws it

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<a-scene embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best;'>
<a-anchor hit-testing-enabled='true'>
    <a-sphere position="0 0.5 0" material="opacity: 1;" color="red"></a-sphere>
</a-anchor>
<a-camera-static/>
</a-scene>
</body>
```

If I aim my phone camera at this image https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/data/images/HIRO.jpg it draws a sphere infront of the it.

Is there a way to make it draw the sphere where I tap on the screen, instead of in front of a specific image? Has anyone been able to find any guides on how to use this ar.js?

Answer (score 2):

ar.js is marker based, as stated in the [docs](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/README.md#full-featured-marker-based).

Using ar.js, you could try to move the objects on the scene by tapping on the screen, but the scene will position itself only on a marker.

Please keep in mind - the screen is a 2D plane, while you want to move an object in the 3D space - You could move it along the *x* and *y* axes, depending where you touch on the screen, but it's clearly not what you want to achieve.

---

You could use [argon.js](https://github.com/argonjs/argon-aframe), but i'm not sure, if their a-frame support is still maintained.